# Should exposed auto-incrementing PKs never be used?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, security, database-design

If a user on the Internet could view the primary key or retrieve data related to it via a browser by entering something like `http://example.com?pk=123`, is it recommended not to use auto-incrementing PKs, and instead use a PK such as `bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(16, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM))` generated by PHP?  Integer keys might be slightly faster and are definitely easier to validate by typecasting, but they potentially give the user too much information.  Please provide rational for your answer.  Thank you

Comment: I think that you should use a alphanumeric ID to display on browser.

Comment: It depends, facebook used to or maybe they still do, someone can chime in on this because i don't use fb anymore, but it seemed the user ids were just AI pk's in the url. Depends on what other security protocols you will put in place.

Comment: I mean that you can keep this auto increament PK, and also create another field to store the alphanumeric ID.

Comment: @Orion Why maintain two columns when a single alphanumerical column would work?

Comment: AI PK is better in almost all cases. Alphanumeric ID is just for the display purpose.

Comment: @Orion.  "AI PK is better in almost all cases." Why do you feel this way? "Alphanumeric ID is just for the display purpose." And when the user wishes to delete, update, etc, right?

Comment: Why do you think `http://example.com?pk=a123` would be better than `http://example.com?pk=123`?

Comment: @davidstrachan.  `a123` is a random number, and the next record would not be `a124`.

Comment: Apart from easy to compare, is there a use/business case that would call for an alphanumeric unique (non primary) key? When one is dealing with ETL, the business case is the table's PK doesn't indicate where the record came from. The thing you need to ask is what can the end user do with a key (of either sort) from a position of modifying the URL they use, or perhaps through the forms the web pages submit. If any of the answers come down to unintended behavior, you'd best look at the Server and client scripts, rather than worrying about the impact from the stance of database design.

Comment: This question makes no sense. Of course it's not "recommended". Who cares if the user can guess the next ID? You can do that on *most* websites. You can do that on Stack Overflow. It's all about *your specific needs*. If you actually have a need for *non* guessable record IDs, then don't use guessable IDs. Otherwise, use whatever is easiest and most performant - typically, sequential autoincremementing ids.

Answer (score 1):

Never? No, of course not never. In most situations, exposing an autoincremented integer is just fine. (For instance, Stack Overflow exposes your user ID of 1032531 all over the place, with no ill effect.) There can be situations where it's unacceptable to expose one, but that's generally based on security concerns, not technical ones. It's entirely dependent on the security concerns relevant to your application.

Keep in mind that there is often a *severe* penalty for using randomly ordered primary keys in databases. The details will depend on the particular database engine and schema you are using, but can be quite significant in some situations. Avoid using random primary keys if at all possible — if possible, use a sequential primary key, and a separate random key as a publicly visible identifier.